# Why most of the codes use Provider package and don't use GetX/Riverpod/Bloc?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-getx, state-management, riverpod

I am learning Flutter. Most of the tutorials use `Provider` package but some others on Youtube use `GetX`. I searched about it and found that it seems there are another packages like `Bloc`, `Riverpod`, etc.

I am confused and don't know which one to use?
It seems `GetX` is simpler than `Provider` and has more capabilities/features like navigation, but there are not a lot of codes/tutorials using that! I wanted to know why? Also which one should I use?

EDIT: Maybe it seems this is like an opinion based question but in my opinion it's not. I want to know why most of the tutorials/open-source codes still use `Provider` package over `GetX`, `Riverpod`, `Bloc`, etc?

Is `Provider` an official package that Flutter supports it and safer to use? Does it have less bugs, etc? Or just it's because it was the first package most of the developers learned to use and it works for them, so they don't like to replace it with even a better one?

Comment: It would go on opinion based I think, I prefer and suggest riverpod>> Bloc now. Also it would be better just not fall for simplicity without considering inner context. Also dont fall for *tutorials* you can check offical docs

Comment: This question asks for opinions. Anyway, I am happy with Getx. The official manual offered by its team is sufficient. The code it requires to get things done is minimal. There are some hiccups when learning how to use it of course, but this is true for all libraries. When in an Enterprise environment, questions like "is this package supported in five years from now" are important to consider.

Comment: because it is the oldest and has the lowest abstraction. it is just wrapper around inherited widget.

Comment: It was put back on the site soon after: https://github.com/flutter/website/pull/4982

Comment: Personally to me (and I am complete beginner) `Obx` and `.obs` are much simpler and right to the point with reactive programming, compare with `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` from Provider. 
When trying to be objective, consider: a) size of community (GetX is biggest); b) speed of development (GetX is faster!) c) functionality (GetX implements "dependency management" design pattern)

I pick GetX for now because it is super simple and fast to develop very complex applications: route management, dependency injections, etc.

Answer (score 7):

---

There are many advantages of the **`Provider`** package specially when combined with ChangeNotifiers-

Its very easy to understand and reason about. The documentation is clear and concise and provides guidelines to best practices as well.
You can use both reactive and non-reactive ChangeNotifiers in a Widget which means that you can depend on other ChangeNotifiers without being notified about changes. This provides many performance benefits.
You can use Provider as a simple dependency injection container as well. The only thing is, you need to have access to the BuildContext attached the widget tree.

---

**`GetX`** is not only a state management library, but instead, it is a microframework combined with route management and dependency injection. It aims to deliver top-of-the-line development experience in an extra lightweight but powerful solution for Flutter. GetX has three basic principles on which it is built:

Performance: focused on minimum consumption of memory and resources

Productivity: intuitive and efficient tool combined with simplicity and straightforward syntax that ultimately saves development time

Organization: decoupling business logic from view and presentation logic cannot get better than this. You do not need context to navigate between routes, nor do you need stateful widgets